# BIOS CPU overclock not sticking with dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, overclocking

I am running a ryzen 7 1700, it's overclocked in the bios up to 4.0 GHz and is stable there. I run a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Every single time I load my Ubuntu distro, my overclock does not work.
The only way to make it work is to enter the bios, exit it (no change required) and then to continue. I can restart into Windows as many times as I want after doing this once and my overclock will stick. As soon as I boot into Ubuntu, it's gone, and my CPU peaks always runs 3.2 GHz.
I have confirmed my CPU governor is set to performance, but I am honestly at a bit of a loss what to do next. I am a Linux newbie, so I'll blame it on that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you conclude the overclocking is not working ?

Comment: @Zulgrib by running the command lscpu and checking clock frequency regularly. It will deviate a couple MHz but sits rock solid at 3.2 GHz, even when i.e. zipping a file on all cores at 100%.

Comment: Did you run mprime https://www.mersenne.org/download/ or similar benchmark ?
Are cpuid and msr kernel module loaded ?

Comment: How did you define the cause is dual booting ? If the system only have Ubuntu installed, do the overclocking set from the motherboard stays ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer will assume you do not have the proper tools installed on your linux distribution and dual boot is not at cause, if this is incorrect, please edit the original question to explain how you determined this issue is specifically caused by dual booting and which tool you used to backup that claim.

**Before starting, take note that you can break things with improper overclocking, if this happen, remember it is you own responsibility.**

You should make sure cpuid and msr kernel modules are activated.

```
sudo modprobe msr cpuid
```

See [manpage of modprobe](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/modprobe.8.html) for more details on this command.
Link provided as is, with no guarantee it will survive time, best to use `man` command from your terminal.

Install a Ryzen frequency control tool, I will use [ZenStates-Linux](https://github.com/r4m0n/ZenStates-Linux/) for this example but you can search for other tools if you don't like this tool.

You will need to `git clone` the repository somewhere, path is up to you.

```
git clone https://github.com/r4m0n/ZenStates-Linux.git
```

Then verify current values.

```
sudo ./zenstates.py  -l
```

On a stock AMD Ryzen 1700x, you should see this. Value will vary with other processors.
Some P states may be enabled or disabled, depending on your motherboard configuration.

```
P0 - Enabled - FID = 88 - DID = 8 - VID = 20 - Ratio = 34.00 - vCore = 1.35000
P1 - Enabled - FID = 78 - DID = 8 - VID = 2C - Ratio = 30.00 - vCore = 1.27500
P2 - Enabled - FID = 84 - DID = C - VID = 68 - Ratio = 22.00 - vCore = 0.90000
P3 - Disabled
P4 - Disabled
P5 - Disabled
P6 - Disabled
P7 - Disabled
C6 State - Package - Enabled
C6 State - Core - Enabled
```

Definition of the values :

FID is Frequency ID in hexadecimal
VID is Voltage ID in hexadecimal
DID is Divisor ID in hexadecimal
Ratio is your CPU clock ratio, multiply it by 100Mhz to get the final clock.
vCore is the CPU base voltage for this P state.

When DID is equal to 8, the formula to get FID is `CPU ratio × 4 = FID`.
The result has to be converted to hexadecimal.
Since your target overclocking is 4Ghz (4000Mhz), FID would be `a0`.

VID goes from 30 (lowest) to 10 (highest) in hexadecimal.
You will need to experiment each values until you achieve the Vcore desired.

On next example, I will set P0 state to 4Ghz with a Vcore of 1,4.

```
sudo ./zenstates.py -p 0 -f 98 -d 8 -v 18
```

This new setting will be lost upon reboot, you can create a systemd service file to apply this change again at boot.

I will assume you copied zenstates.py to $PATH.

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/overclock.service
```

Inside this file, add these values.

```
[Unit]
Description=Overclock
DefaultDependencies=no
After=sysinit.target local-fs.target
Before=basic.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=zenstates.py -p 0 -f 98 -d 8 -v 18

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Verify service is working :

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable overclock
sudo systemctl start overclock
```

If system become unbootable, boot to recovery and delete or edit the service file.
Test stability using these projects.

https://github.com/akopytov/sysbench

https://www.mersenne.org/download/

https://github.com/stressapptest/stressapptest

https://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=downloads

You may want to do the stress test from a different dedicated installation of your favorite linux distribution, in case of data corruption due to instability.

Operate these tweaks with caution.

Other tools that may get the job done : [Ryzen Controller](https://gitlab.com/ryzen-controller-team/ryzen-controller), [CoreFreq](https://github.com/cyring/CoreFreq) ([soon](https://github.com/cyring/CoreFreq/commit/4a9183fa88b5be4af2cb439fa8c0219d4f638831))